# Nginx Always Return 404 When Pointing to A Specific URL with Parameters

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vuejs3, nginx-config

I am makin a web apps using Vue.js 3. Everything goes well when running on the npm run serve. Problem occurs when serving the web app using NGINX. It always returning nginx 404 default page when pointing to a specific url with parameter.

For example when filling a form or editing data with a specific uuid -->

http://www.example.com/edit_form/sdnsaiodaiondiondq

where sdnsaiodaiondiondq is a random uuid.

when I share the link to someone and they directly access the link, it returns 404. However if they open it from the home page and manually enter or choose which data to edit, it works (the link is the same)

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I expext the my user could access the page directly from my customize link with the uuid info instead of going from the main page and choose which data to edit

Comment: Look at the Nginx access log. Find both entries and compare.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, I have checked the access log and it only log the error occurs due to GET request to the path --> GET /edit_form/sdnsaiodaiondiondq not found